# Calculate year-over-year changes based month-over-month changes and values in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Given a sample data which could be downloaded from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/z3eoaw6fgu0dna01hqpep/sample_data1.xlsx?dl=0&rlkey=5wtl9fz2c1hcyovh7exw7au8x):

[image]

Let's say the `MoM` columns values in `2022-04-30` are monthly changes predicted with unit percentage (%).

I will need to calculate year over year changes based on MoM and value columns for import and export separately.

I have achieved that with code below, but how could convert it to a function to make it easier to implement for multiple columns (let's if I have other columns: GDP_MoM, GDP_value, CPI_MoM, CPI_value, etc. in `df`)? Thanks for your help at advance.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel('./sample_data1.xlsx')
df.tail(5)

df['import_value_YoY_based_MoM'] = ((df['import_MoM']/100 +1)*df['import_value'].shift(1) / df['import_value'].shift(12))-1
df['export_value_YoY_based_MoM'] = ((df['export_MoM']/100 +1)*df['export_value'].shift(1) / df['export_value'].shift(12))-1

df['import_value_YoY'] = df['import_value'] / df['import_value'].shift(12) -1 
df['export_value_YoY'] = df['export_value'] / df['export_value'].shift(12) -1 
print(df.tail(5))
```

Out:

[image]

Comment: please provide (a sample of) the input data as reproducible text/DataFrame

Comment: I've posted in dropbox, please click the hyperlink to download.

Comment: can't you just provide the 5 lines shown in the question?

Comment: Since its monthly data, I'll need to calculate year-over-year changes, so sample data should be at least 13 lines or more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use custom funtion with `f-string`s with input for both columns names in pairs in list `cols`:

```
def f(df, col1, col2):
    df[f'{col2}_YoY_based_{col1}'] = ((df[col1]/100 +1)*df[col2].shift(1) / df[col2].shift(12))-1
    df[f'{col2}_YoY'] = df[col2] / df[col2].shift(12) -1 
    return df

cols = [('import_MoM','import_value'), ('export_MoM','export_value')]
for col1, col2 in cols:
    df = f(df, col1, col2)
```